# Ubuntu BASH Script Background Job Hide Windows

Tags: linux, bash, background-process

I have a seemingly simple problem that I can't figure out how to solve.

I have a bash script which launches a program in the background within a loop. However, each time the program opens up it launches a window and focuses on it. Is there a way to launch a process and have all of the windows which it launches be minimized or completely suppressed?

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
process1 & P=$!; #I need to hide all of the windows in this process
process2;
kill $P;
wait;
sleep 0.1; done
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What's this program? Isn't an option to start minimalized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use xdotool, replace name_in_titlebar with the name from your titlebar :D

```
xdotool search --name name_in_titlebar windowactivate
xdotool key ctrl+super+Up
```

Answer (score 1):

This is up to the Window Manager. Try looking up [how to prevent focus stealing](http://bertrandbenoit.blogspot.com/2011/09/change-window-behavior-to-prevent-focus.html) in your wm documentation.

For a more general approach, you can start a second X server (`startx -- :1` and then `Ctrl-Alt-F8` to switch to it), run an instance of `Xnest` to get an X-server-in-a-window where subwindows won't steal focus, or run a vncserver/nxserver that the windows can spam and you can occasionally connect to and look at if you want. With any of these set up on e.g. display `:1`, you can redirect your process's window with `DISPLAY=:1 process1`.